# Rails Console error after upgrading to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5.1, ruby-on-rails-5.2

After upgrading from ubuntu 16.04 to ubuntu 18.04 I am receiving the following error when running `rails console` from the root directory of rails project.  Only the console seems to be affected, I am able to start the puma server without issue.

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 23887
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require': libreadline.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/x86_64-linux/readline.so (LoadError)
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/irb/completion.rb:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands/console/console_command.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:82:in `block (2 levels) in lookup'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:78:in `each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:78:in `block in lookup'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:77:in `each'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command/behavior.rb:77:in `lookup'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command.rb:68:in `find_by_namespace'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/command.rb:42:in `invoke'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/railties-5.1.6/lib/rails/commands.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
    from /home/user/dev/projects/SRTrackerMySQL/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `block in load'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
    from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.1/gems/activesupport-5.1.6/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:286:in `load'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from /home/user/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.4.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `require'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I've run `bundle install` and tried it with new rails projects with both `Rails 5.1.6` and `Rails 5.2`

I also tried running `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rails console`

I'm using Ruby version:

```
ruby 2.4.1p111 (2017-03-22 revision 58053) [x86_64-linux]
```

Comment: Did you read the very first line of the error message?  That should give you some insight.  The missing file is in a 2.4.0 but you're using 2.4.1

Comment: I had the same issue after upgrading to Ubuntu 19.04 using Ruby 2.6.0

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to make sure readline is installed.  You're using RVM, so you can run:

`rvm requirements`

and it should help make sure you have everything installed that you need, followed by:

`rvm reinstall 2.4.1`

if needed to make sure your ruby is good to go.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same exact issue but we use `rbenv` instead of `rvm`. A similar answer to Brian's worked for me:

```
rbenv uninstall 2.4.1
rbenv install 2.4.1
```

Comment: Yup. Pretty sure you don't need to run the uninstall command, though (and not kill running projects).  Just run rbenv install <whatever>, and it will ask you if you want to replace.

Comment: I've had the same issue when upgrading from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04. This solution worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

Running the following code on the terminal solved the problem for me:

```
cd /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libreadline.so.7.0 libreadline.so.6
```

Comment: That is a total hack, but it works. Same for version 8 when 7 is needed.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem after upgrading. My guess is the problem happens with the RVM.

so, first uninstall the RVM.

```
rvm implode
```

And then, do the following commands to install the RVM again

```
sudo apt install gnupg2
gpg2 --keyserver hkp://keys.gnupg.net --recv-keys 409B6B1796C275462A1703113804BB82D39DC0E3 7D2BAF1CF37B13E2069D6956105BD0E739499BDB
cd /tmp
curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io -o rvm.sh
less /tmp/rvm.sh
cat /tmp/rvm.sh | bash -s stable --rails
source /home/admat/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

Reload the RVM

```
rvm reload
```

Install your ruby version

```
rvm install _version_
```

Don the bundle command to install gems

```
bundle install
```

DONE !!!!!

if you want more details on installing ruby to ubuntu 18.04, try the following link
[Install ruby on rails with Ubuntu 18.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 2):

Reinstalling Ruby and rehashing rbenv didn't work for me. In the end I went for a simple symlink of the current installed `libreadline.so7`

```
locate libreadline.so
```

This returned a whole list of possible options, but the most likely usable one appeared to be `/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.7`

```
sudo ln -s /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.7 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6
```

Once linked, I can now run `rails console` and use `byebug` again.

Answer (score 1):

I also was not able to run `rails console` after upgrading Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04. I was getting something similar to this:

```
-bash: error while loading shared libraries: libreadline.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I had to reinstall rvm again following the instructions posted here:
https://github.com/rvm/ubuntu_rvm